# Comma in a field of a CSV file is causing mongoimport to read one field as multiple values

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I am using this command to insert all the values from file_name.csv to a MongoDb data base.

```
cat file_name.csv | awk -F',' 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {print $1,$2,$3,$8,$9,$10}' | mongoimport --type csv --db test --collection test2 --headerline
```

The problem is one of the field's value,in file_name.csv, has variable number of commas in it too. So, when I try to fetch the required data using '$1,$2,$3,$8,$9,$10', the field with commas in it is getting split on comma and is being read multiple times.

Is there a way to read the complete value as one and not multiple values ?
And i would prefer the answer that uses mongoimport, thanks !

Comment: It is problem of awk separator you are using and not mongoimport..http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/snipplets/awkcsv

Comment: Yeah you are right, but the solution on the link doesn't work for me. I have only one filed which is enclosed in quotes and it has commas inside. The solution is if every field is enclosed in quotes. @Undefined_variable

Comment: If your input is valid CSV file, I'm wondering why are using Awk? mongoimport supports csv out of box

Comment: @Saleem I only want to insert certain fields, and this seemed to be the best option...that's why am using awk